# If $x^2-3x+9=0$, can we say $(x+3)(x^2-3x+9)$ is also $0$ hence $x^3=-27$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, problem-solving

I was solving this question

> If $\dfrac x3 + \dfrac 3x = 1$ then find the value of $x^3$.

I solved it as. Cube both sides and substitute $x^3$ with $t$, 
$$ \dfrac{t}{27} + \dfrac{27}{t}=-2$$
$$\implies t^2 + {27}^2 + 2\cdot 27 \cdot t = 0$$
$$\implies (t+27)^2=0$$
$$\implies t=x^3=-27$$

Someone over facebook put another solution as,

$$\dfrac x3 + \dfrac 3x = 1$$
$$\implies x^2-3x+9=0$$

Multiplying both the sides with $(x+3)$,

$$(x+3)(x^2-3x+9)=0$$
$$\implies x^3+27=0$$

Hence $x^3=-27$.

My question is, is it correct to multiply both sides with $0$? ( $x+3$ is $0$ here because $x^3=-27 \implies x=-3$ is one possible solution and other two being complex numbers.)

Comment: $x = -3$ is not a solution to the original equation.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Suppose we are given that  $x^2-4x+4=0$ then can we multiply both sides with $x+2$ and conclude $x^3=-8$?

Comment: Take a simpler example. Let $f(x) = x$ and we want to find the solutions to $x=0$ (which is just $0$ as you know; i.e. the origin of the straight line). Now multiply both sides by $(x+1)$ to get $(x+1)*x = 0$. But is $x = -1$ a solution to the original function?

Comment: $(x+2)(x^2-4x+4)=0$ does not give $x^3=-8$.

Comment: Ok. I mistook the formula $(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)$

Comment: Short answer, yes.  Also, Given $x^2-2x+4=0$ you could multiply by $(x+2)$ and conclude $x^3=-8$. However this step is non-reversible, for e.g. $x^2=2x-4\implies x^3=-8$ but the reverse implication is not always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is nothing as such wrong with this process since it really helps in identifying the roots.

BUT **one thing to keep in mind** is that when you multiply the expression with $(x+3)$, you are introducing [extraneous roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions). That is, you had a quadratic equation with 2 roots and you have now made it cubic with 3 roots. So after solving, you must carefully eradicate this extraneous root you had introduced.

In the given problem, $x=-3$ is the extraneous root.

However you could have approached the problem using the discriminant.Then you get the roots easily.

$$x^2-3x+9=0 \Rightarrow x=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{9-36}}{2}=\frac{3 \pm 3\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$

Comment: Now, if you rise $\frac{3 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ to the power 3, you will get $x^3=-27$.

Comment: @kmitov What do you mean?....:-)

Comment: PErhaps he meant does cubing $ x=\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{9-36}}{2}=\frac{3 \pm 3\sqrt{3}i}{2}$ give $-27$?

Comment: Just to complete your answer.

Comment: @kmitov Yes, from the root we get $x^3=-27$ but that process should be avoided. It is better to solve the equation as I have done it.

Comment: But the question is "what is the value of $x^3$?"

Comment: No, you can't. Because $(x+2)(x^2-4x+4)=(x+2)(x-2)^2=(x^2-4)(x-2)=x^3-2x^2-4x+8 \not = x^3+8$.

Comment: @kmitov The question according to the OP is if he can multiply both sides of his equation by some factor $(x+3)$ and conclude a different equation. It is not about any value of $x^3$. If   user103816  is reading this, confirm if I am right or not.

Comment: Yes that was my main question that can I multiply both sides with (x+3) or not. I thought x=-3 is correct root so I am multiplying both sides with 0. But  actually $x+3 \neq 0$ so what we are doing is $0=0$ so $(x+3)0=0$ is also true. But the resultant equation will also contain the extraneous root. I guess user 'kmitov' is concerned about your first and last line "_since it really helps in identifying the roots_". I didn't get how this helps in finding the roots.

Comment: From $x^3=-27=(-3)^3$, can't you easily conclude that the roots of this equation are $-3,-3\omega,-3\omega^2$ where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity and then leave out $-3$ as the extraneous root? This is what I meant by that line. If you check my way of computing the roots, you will see that what I got there was $-3\omega,-3\omega^2$ only. Thats what I wanted to say. Now am I clear?

Comment: . What I meant is that from the wording of your question it seems that you took the question as _"How to find the root of..."_. Anyhow this made me learn to find the root too. Thanks for explaining. :-)